# How to redirect output of user defined class to view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am facing the following problem.

I am making a naive Bayes gender prediction algorithm in rails. For that I have coded it and put my code file in roots directory. I am able to access the class in  my Model controller and run the code by appropriate calling of class.

I have a form with three fields "weight, height and gender", when I fill all these three, they should get saved in the db. I have written its logic and it works well. In case I leave out the gender field as it is, it should run my code and render an appropriate view.

In the create action of controller I am doing the following:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.gender.blank?
       @b_obj= Bayes.new
       @b_obj.predict(@user[height], @user[weight]).
    else
      if @user.save
        redirect_to @user
      else
        @title = "Train"
        render 'new'
      end
    end
  end
```

This code works well. Now I am faced with the problem, how to redirect the result of my code (first if statement) to a view and where to make it. My code returns "male" or "female" as an output. Should I store it in some variable? how should I go about it?

This is the last thing left in my project. After trying many approaches I have come to this, but now I am in sort of a deadlock.

Regards,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra boolean attribute to your user object called 'gender_predicted' which would indicate whether the gender set for the user is predicted or was specified:

```
@user.gender = @b_obj.predict(@user[height], @user[weight])
@user.gender_predicted = true
```

That would allow you to store your prediction and only have to run it once.  Then you can treat all users the same way but still allow you to track where predictions have been used.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.gender ||= Bayes.new.predict(@user[height], @user[weight])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = 'User saved'
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Train"
      render 'new'
    end
end
```